# Styling different levels of itemize with repeating item numbers in ConTeXt

Tags: context, itemize

As ugly as this sounds, is it possible to produce a nested itemize list with different styles for each item number? E.g. with the below code:

```
\setupbodyfont[sansserif]
\starttext

\setupitemize[1][n,repeat,joinedup][width=1em]
\setupitemize[2][n,repeat,joinedup][style=bold,width=2em]
\setupitemize[3][n][width=3em]

\startitemize
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
  \startitemize
  \item Item 2.1
  \item Item 2.2
    \startitemize
    \item Item 2.2.1
    \item Item 2.2.2
    \stopitemize
  \stopitemize
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

This produces:

[image: Actual Result]

But what I'm looking for is (manually produced):

[image: Desired Result]

Is this possible? Or might this require some serious ugly hacks? Furthermore, is it possible to not only bold item numbers, but instead also overstrike them as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. But I have no idea if this is the right way and if it has nasty side effect:

```
\setupbodyfont[sansserif]

\definebar[thickoverstrike][overstrike][offset=0.75,rulethickness=.25]
\def\boldovernumber#1{{\bf\thickoverstrike{#1}}}
\defineconversion[o][\boldovernumber]

\setupitemize[1][n,repeat,joinedup,][width=1em]
\setupitemize[2][o,repeat,joinedup] [width=2em]
\setupitemize[3][n][width=3em]

\starttext
\startitemize
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
  \startitemize
  \item Item 2.1
  \item Item 2.2
    \startitemize
    \item Item 2.2.1
    \item Item 2.2.2      
    \stopitemize
  \stopitemize
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: That's how I would have done it as well, perhaps with a thicker overstrike.

Comment: @Aditya: So not so bad for a latex user ;-). If you tell me how to do a thicker overstrike I will add it.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the thick overbar (and moved the setups to the preamble). I hope that you don't mind.

Comment: Perfect! Works exactly as I need it to :)